# What is this black spot in my kitten's snout?

Tags: cats, health, skin-condition

My kitten is 7 weeks old and there is this dark spot in his nose, which is slightly protruding. It appeared about a week ago and it has only been growing since then. I started getting worried when the right "cheek" started being affected, but now it has spread to both sides.

[image]

[image]

[image]

He doesn't seem to react any differently when I touch him there than anywhere else in the face, but I believe I've seen him scratching it once or twice before

I've read some other similar questions, but my cat's spot looks huge in comparison. How severe does it look and what should I do?